# Custom API Mobile Services Azure IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql-server, mobile, azure

I want to create an Custom API script that uses mssql. I want to be able to do a simple t-sql command, at the moment something like select * from notifications will do fine. 
then how can I receive the result from within a NSLOG command ? I have been playing with InvokeAPI call on iOS and I cannot seem to fathom out how to get the results back. I can read a JSON , Hello world easy from a Custom API. Any ideas , really simple would do perfectly then i can build from that.

Any help would be great.

thanks

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in the completion block of the iOS SDK's invokeAPI method is "id result".  If you do

```
NSLog(@"Result: %@", result)
```

inside of that completion handler, it will log whatever data you send back.  As for performing the SQL command in your script, you'll want to do something like this in your custom API script:

```
mssql.queryRaw(sql, null, {
    success: function(results) {
        response.send(200, results);
    }, error: function(error) {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
        response.send(400, { Error : error});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats all cool and I have it working, but what if i wanted to pass a variable from IOS to the azure Custom API, so if i wanted to put the ID = 3 on the IOS side and then run the query in the Custom API with the ID = 3 ?

Comment: See my answer on your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677572/passing-variables-between-ios-with-invokeapi-and-mobile-services-custom-api/21684122#21684122

Comment: There should be a closing curly-bracket in the error response: `response.send(400, { Error : error }); `

Comment: Thanks.  Formatting has been fixed.