# Passing variables between IOS with InvokeAPI and mobile services custom API

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure

I can do  a quick SQL query within a custom API using the InbokeAPI method on iOS, but how would I pass a variable between iOS and the SQL Query within the customAPi so I can choose the ID row for example ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call invoke API you can pass a JSON object over as the body.  In your server side script, you can then pull that value out and use it as a parameter for your sql query.  So on the client side you'd do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *postValues = @{ @"myParam": @"myValue"};
[self.client invokeAPI:@"myAPI" body:postValues
```

Then on the server side in your custom API script, you'd do something like this:

```
var value = request.body.myParam;
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = ?";
var mssql = request.service.mssql;
mssql.queryRaw(sql, [value], {
  success: function(results) {
     //do stuff for success
  }, error: function(error) {
     //do stuff for error
  });
```

Comment: Great one Chris, I will have a play and accept your answer. cheers!